# Firebase topics notifications not receiving on android device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Am not getting topics notifications. Console shows its send successfully and return message id, but device not receiving it. Once i got both single and topics messages , after i add some UI changes it not receiving topics messages. what is the issue?

I am registering the topic on my launcher activity onCreate method.

There is no issue in single device notification send and receiving.

**Bellow is my broadcastreceiver code.**

```
 mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("Main activity: ","gcm = "+intent.getAction());
            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                Log.e("Main activity: ","gcm successfully registered");
                // gcm successfully registered
                // now subscribe to `global` topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Config.TOPIC_GLOBAL);


            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received
                Log.e("Main activity: ","gcm successfully registered 2");
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // txtMessage.setText(message);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: why are you using a broadcast receiver?

Comment: for receiving notification intent

Comment: Did you fix this, I am experiencing the same issue